# Twitter API - unable to update status containing round parenthesis

Tags: java, twitter, jersey-client

I am trying to use Twitter API for tweeting using an access token.
When i am using the API for posting a status like "Hey guys", it succeeds and i can see the tweet on my timeline, but when i post "Hey guys :)" i get the following response:

```
{errors=[{code=32, message=Could not authenticate you.}]}
```

Here is the request that succeeds (sending "hey guys"):

```
 client.target("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json")
.queryParam("status", "hey%20guys")
.request()
.post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.text("sdfsdf"))
.readEntity(Object.class);
```

Here is the request that fails (sending "hey guys :)" ):

```
 client.target("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json")
.queryParam("status", "hey%20guys%20%3A)")
.request()
.post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.text("sdfsdf"))
.readEntity(Object.class);
```

For encoding the text I used http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

For sending requests using the API i use javax.ws.rs.client.Client.

I have also tried to find any reference in [Twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update) for this issue but didn't find anything related.
Their API contains an example for posting but i can post that one as well.

Comment: Did you try encoding the parenthesis? %29

Comment: Thanks, that was the thing... it's weird since i have tried 3 different online URL encodes, all keeping the parenthesis in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encode the parenthesis, that will fix it.

```
status = status.replaceAll("\\(","%28").replaceAll("\\)","%29"); 

client.target("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json")
.queryParam("status", status)
.request()
...
```